# How to run ANTLR 3.4 in command line?

Tags: antlr3

I have tried to run ANTLR 3.4
in these ways:

```
java -classpath "d:\extracted\antlrworks1.4.3" org.antlr.Tool %p%\parser.g -o %p%\output
or
java -classpath "%p%lib\antlrworks-1.4.3.jar" org.antlr.Tool %p%\parser.g -o %p%\output
or
java -classpath "%p%lib\antlr-3.4.jar;%p%lib\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar;%p%lib\ST4-4.0.4.jar" org.antlr.Tool %p%\parser.g -o %p%\output

Each of them resulted in the same error message;

Message ILLEGAL_OPTION_VALUE in locale en_US not found
Message ALL_OPS_NEED_SAME_ASSOC in locale en_US not found
ANTLR installation corrupted; English messages file en.stg incomplete
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: ANTLR ErrorManager panic
    at org.antlr.tool.ErrorManager.panic(ErrorManager.java:918)
    at org.antlr.tool.ErrorManager.setLocale(ErrorManager.java:427)
    at org.antlr.tool.ErrorManager.<clinit>(ErrorManager.java:390)
    at org.antlr.tool.CompositeGrammar.createNFAs(CompositeGrammar.java:379)
    at org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:466)
    at org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:93)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The message says "ANTLR installation corrupted" -- have you tried downloading it again?

Answer (score 3):

I no longer use v3, except to answer some questions. I use

```
$ export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/lib/antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar
```

once for all, and "compile" the grammar with

```
$ java org.antlr.Tool Question.g
```

then compile

```
$ javac Question*.java Test.java
```

then execute

```
$ java Test
```

Precision : the file Test.java contains :

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        QuestionLexer lexer = new QuestionLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        QuestionParser parser = new QuestionParser(tokens);
        parser.question();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that v4 is simpler and more powerful ? To start with, please check _Antlr 3 and 4_ in the Discuss tab of the ANTLR4 book http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference

Answer (score 0):

I fIgured out.
The current directory has to be the same as the location of jars.